# opencv 3.0 not working on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I was using opencv 3.0 on eclipse in ubuntu 15.04 and it was working fine, i updated to ubuntu 15.10 and now even a simple code is giving me errors. I think some files or libraries got misplaced or deleted, I have tried dozens of things but none seems to be working. Here's the eclipse output

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "DisplayImage"  ./src/DisplayImage.o   -lopencv_core -lopencv_hal -lopencv_viz -lopencv_flann -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_ml -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_photo -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavcodec.so.56, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
makefile:45: recipe for target 'DisplayImage' failed
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavformat.so.56, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libavutil.so.54, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libswscale.so.3, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libIlmImf.so.6, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libHalf.so.6, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_id@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_frame@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_encoder@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_close@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_guess_codec@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_write_header@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_sub_q@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::hasChromaticities(Imf::Header const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::Chromaticities::Chromaticities(Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_opt_set@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_seek_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_flush_buffers@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avpicture_get_size@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_tag@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::globalThreadCount()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_guess_format@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_alloc_context@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::chromaticities(Imf::Header const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_write_trailer@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_open2@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::setFrameBuffer(Imf::FrameBuffer const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::header() const'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avio_open@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_video2@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::InputFile(char const*, int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_register_all@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::~OutputFile()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_getCachedContext@LIBSWSCALE_3'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_new_stream@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_rescale_q@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_init_packet@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::setFrameBuffer(Imf::FrameBuffer const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_scale@LIBSWSCALE_3'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_freeContext@LIBSWSCALE_3'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::Header::channels() const'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::Header::channels()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_malloc@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_freep@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::Header::~Header()'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_free_context@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `sws_getContext@LIBSWSCALE_3'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::OutputFile(char const*, Imf::Header const&, int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_free@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::Header::Header(int, int, float, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, float, Imf::LineOrder, Imf::Compression)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_context_defaults3@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::writePixels(int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_free_packet@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_write_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avpicture_fill@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_dict_free@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_open_input@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_network_init@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_find_stream_info@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `half::_eLut'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_video2@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::Header::dataWindow() const'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_log_set_level@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_lockmgr_register@LIBAVCODEC_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_read_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_close_input@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::readPixels(int, int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `half::convert(int)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `av_dict_set@LIBAVUTIL_54'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so: undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avio_close@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so: undefined reference to `avformat_get_riff_video_tags@LIBAVFORMAT_56'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> `warning: libIlmImf.so.6, needed by .../libopencv_imgcodecs.so`

Clearly `libopencv_imgcodecs.so` depends on `libIlmImf.so.6`, yet you are not using the latter on your link line.

You should append `-lIlmImf` to your link, and that will likely solve all the `Imf::...` problems. Repeat with other libraries that the linker told you to add.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [libav](https://libav.org/download/) installed on ubuntu? This library is used by OpenCV to read the different video formats. You can probably find the .so files in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib and then add it to you G++ call. I'm not familiar with Eclipse, but you should be able to follow [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1873479) to add the dependency.